# Bitshift with unsigned value gives signed result

Tags: go, bit-shift, unsigned

Doing a bitshift operation with unsigned `uint32` variables, why is signed `int` result received?

```golang
func NewNM(log2Dim uint32) {
    SIZE := 1 << (3 * log2Dim) // Why: SIZE type == int
    // ...
}
```

Comment: You’re not shifting an unsigned value, you’re shifting `1` using an unsigned value, so the result is based on `1`

Comment: Use `uint32(1) << (3 * log2Dim)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [go language reference](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Operators)

> The right operand in a shift expression must have integer type or be
> an untyped constant representable by a value of type uint. If the left
> operand of a non-constant shift expression is an untyped constant, it
> is first implicitly converted to the type it would assume if the shift
> expression were replaced by its left operand alone.

and later...

> The shift operators shift the left operand by the shift count
> specified by the right operand, which must be non-negative. If the
> shift count is negative at run time, a run-time panic occurs. The
> shift operators implement arithmetic shifts if the left operand is a
> signed integer and logical shifts if it is an unsigned integer.

So the `1` in the expression `1 << (3 * log2Dim)` is converted to an `int` according to the first paragraph, and then the shift is an arithmetic shift according to the second paragraph.